# Counting probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If 10 people, including Jack and Tim, are randomly arranged in a line, what is the probability that Jack and Tim are next to each other?

Comment: $\frac{9\cdot8!+9\cdot8!}{10!}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As always, go back to the classical definition of probability.

Number of ways in which you can arrange 10 people in a line such that 2 of them are always together: 2*(9!) This can be understood by treating the two people who are supposed to be together as one person. You can then arrange these 9 people in 9! ways. In every permutation, the group of two people can appear in 2 ways, that is AB or BA. So, total number of ways will be 2*(9!).

Total number of ways to arrange 10 people in a line: 10!

Probability = Favourable outcomes / Total Outcomes = (2*(9!))/(10!) = 1/5

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{2}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{9}+\frac{8}{10}\cdot\frac{2}{9}=\frac{18}{90}=\frac{1}{5}.$$

$$\frac{2}{10} = {\rm Pr}(\text{Jack in the first or last position})$$

$$\frac{1}{9} = {\rm Pr}(\text{Tim is next to Jack | Jack in the first or last position}),$$

$$\frac{8}{10} = {\rm Pr}(\text{Jack in any position except first and last position})$$

$$\frac{2}{9} = {\rm Pr}(\text{Tim is the next to Jack | Jack in any position except first and last position})$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is
$$\dfrac{9! \cdot 2!}{10!}$$

Comment: Your answer is correct, but you should explain how you arrived at it so that the person who posted the question understands why it is correct.